# Scrolling parallax effect for Narrative Theme - Shopify

Tags: shopify, parallax, parallax.js, shopify-template

I am building my online store lately with Shopify but I would like to have the scrolling parallax effect for the header in the theme. I am trying to do this for hours and wasn't able to make it work.

Also, there's a way to create a new section for the theme using one background image (with the scrolling parallax effect as well) and having a "contact us" form on top of the image?

Thanks in advance and I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow. We will be happy to help you if you provide us with information what have you tried ( in code ) and what is the exact problem that you are dealing with. StackOverflow is not a "write the code for me" platform.

Comment: also it would be nice to specify the parallax library you are using. is it [pixelcog/parallax.js](https://github.com/pixelcog/parallax.js) ?